# how to visible button for a button

Tags: android, database, button

i want to make a button visible, when score in database more than 20
mycode:

```
mScoreDataAdapter = new DBDataSource(this);
mScoreDataAdapter.open();
LevelUnsur rs = mScoreDataAdapter.getskor(1);
int a = rs.getSkor();
if(a > 20){
    level2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);         
}
```

In the above mycode is not working. so please tell me an answer for the above problem or tell me if there is any other method for visible on button if skor in database more than 20 
in my logcat error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tugasakhir/com.example.tugasakhir.menuleveldasar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Since you get `NullPointerexception`, maybe rs is null. Or you have forgotten to initialize `level2`.

Comment: You should just add two if statements verifying that `rs` and `level2` are not `null`. If either one of them is just use the `Log.v(TAG, message); `method to log it.

Comment: you don't have enough code here for anyone to diagnose what's wrong.  Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited code that is supplied, I assume that the null pointer is raised due to the following line:

```
LevelUnsur rs = mScoreDataAdapter.getskor(1);
```

If the getskor method does not return a value for 1 as an input, then rs will be null.

Try to change it to :

```
LevelUnsur rs = mScoreDataAdapter.getskor(0);
```

PS. Why are you entering 1 into that method, the logic isn't clear at this stage.

Comment: because data of score in database is 20, i've kept it in the previous activity

Comment: data in LevelUnsur rs = mScoreDataAdapter.getskor(1);
if score.setText(""+rs.getScore()); it show 20